# Sqlprojects: Stores and views with references to other database not compiling

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012, data-warehouse, sql-server-data-tools

I have a database made for datawarehousing with views that aim to more than 1 db.

so after leveling production with my databases of qa and dev, I made an Sqlproject to allow my team to work with ssdt, and all the auto-stuff that it provides.

But when I try to compile it throws lots of *"I don't get the reference to the other db"* errors...

> THIS_VIEW.sql(30,27): Error:  SQL71561: View: [dbo].[THIS_VIEW] has an
> unresolved reference to object [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[MYTABLE].[FOO].
>
> THIS_VIEW.sql(31,25): Error:  SQL71561: View: [dbo].[THIS_VIEW] has an
> unresolved reference to object [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[MYTABLE].[BAR].
>
> THIS_VIEW.sql(32,4): Error:  SQL71561: View: [dbo].[THIS_VIEW] has an
> unresolved reference to object [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[MYTABLE].[BAZ].
>
> THIS_VIEW.sql(33,4): Error:  SQL71561: View: [dbo].[THIS_VIEW] has an
> unresolved reference to object [OTHER_DB].[dbo].[MYTABLE].[QUX].

How could I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add some database references to your project. I usually have done this by creating a dacpac for the "Other_DB" database, putting that in some location that all database projects could access (usually the folder one level above the solutions), and adding a database reference without the option to use a variable for the database name.

I have written this up on my blog here:
http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-external-database-references.html

You can use SQLPackage to extract a dacpac from your existing database if VS/SSDT does not work. I've had mixed success using the GUI tools to create a dacpac file.

Comment: Peter, I'll be testing that, great work on your blog, please keep posting on SSDT!
I'm actually trying to set up a SSDT based LifeCycle, but I'm also having some trouble with data encryption and deployment. 
I should set different keys on UAT, Production and Development environments. This sounds a lot like the work you've done on the last post but I'm newbie on this tech so I'll have a lot hard work on deducing how to do what I need.
If you have plans on a new entry, please consider writing one on dacpac deploy with different field encryption on each env (for the same fields).
KeepUpTGoodWrk!

Comment: I'll see what I can do, but we don't tend to use SQL data encryption right now. I imagine you could do it with partial projects - using one main project for everything non-encrypted and different projects for the objects w/ the encrypted columns. You'd include your main project in the sub-project and deploy those sub-projects. Jamie Thomson blogged about it here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2013/03/10/deployment-of-client-specific-database-code-using-ssdt.aspx